# How to build Docker images for Windows in Jenkins

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins, build, docker-image

I do have a Jenkins instance running in a Linux machine. I would also like to build Docker Images (Windows containers). I was not able to find an example anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out there is a plugin for Jenkins that is able to interact with cloud/remote Docker installations. https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/

You just need to enable remote acces in the Docker Daemon Configuration as below and configure the plugin to use this installation as a its builder.

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false,
  "hosts": [
    "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont need windows machine to build windows container you can build on linux or on windows base machine.
1)create a freestyle job 
2) checkout code with docker file
3) select execute shell command  section of build in jenkins job configaration write docker build . 
if docker file is at  project level  or give path of docker file inste6d of mentioning .
4) voila container is build